# An example of cover and subcover

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Suppose 
$$X=\{1,2,3 \}$$
$$C=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{1,3\}\}$$
$$U=\{\{2\},\{1,3\}\}$$
Can I say that $C$ is a cover of $X$ and $U$ is a subcover of $C$?
If not,why?

Comment: Yes, you can say that. And moreover what you're saying then is true. A "sample" of cover and subcover? I would rather speak of an "example".

Comment: Yes, thank you. @drhab

Comment: Is that  the definition of open cover?I think  the definition of cover and subcover need not to be open.@yanko

Comment: @yanko In that case I would speak of "open cover".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use the definitions. $\cup C$ is the set of the members of the members of $C.$ That is, $x\in \cup C\iff \exists d\in C\;(x\in d).$

$C$ is a cover of $X $ iff $\cup C\supset X.$ If $C$ is a cover of $X$ then $D$ is a sub-cover of $C$ iff $D\subset C$ and $\cup D\supset X.$

It would be more logical to say "$D$ is a sub($X$)-cover  of $C$" or something like that, because whether  or not $D$ is a sub-cover of $C$ depends upon the $X$ that is being covered, unless $\cup D=\cup C.$

With $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and $C=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{1,3\}\}$ we have

$$x\in \cup C\iff (x\in \{1\}\lor x\in \{2\}\lor x\in \{1,3\})\iff x\in \{1,2,3\}=X.$$ So $\cup C=X.$ So $C$ is a cover of $X.$

And $U=\{\{2\}\}, \{1,3\}\}\subset C$ with $\cup U=\cup C=X,\;$ so $ U$ is a sub-cover of $C.$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can say it, and it's even true ;): $\bigcup C = X$ and $\bigcup U = X$ with $U \subseteq C$.

Note that any cover of a finite space is finite (there are only finitely many subsets to make the cover) and is its own subcover.